# Trouble installing rlinkedin package

Tags: r

Im having trouble installing `Rlinkedin` package, I have tried installing it through a mirror as well as by downloading the tar file. when I got the `httr` package error, I have installed that as well manually. Not sure what am I missing.

```
installing *source* package 'Rlinkedin' ...
** package 'Rlinkedin' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** preparing package for lazy loading
Warning: package 'httr' was built under R version 3.2.2
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  there is no package called 'stringi'
Error : package 'httr' could not be loaded
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'Rlinkedin'
* removing 'D:/C Drive/ms5017864/Documents/R/win-library/3.1/Rlinkedin'
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.0/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "D:\C Drive\ms5017864\Documents\R\win-library\3.1" "D:/CDRIVE~1/MS5017~1/DOCUME~1/R/WIN-LI~1/3.1/Rlinkedin_0.1.tar.gz"' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘D:/CDRIVE~1/MS5017~1/DOCUME~1/R/WIN-LI~1/3.1/Rlinkedin_0.1.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: Upgrade your version of R from `3.2.1` to `3.2.2`, as `httr` was built under the latter.

Comment: Try `install.packages("Rlinkedin", dependencies = T)`